# Optimization of squaring or multiplying each element in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, optimization, matrix

I have two questions that I would like to ask.

1. First one is that there is an array of hf = {1, 4, 9, ........, n-1, n}.  I would like to square of each elements in the array like {1^2, 4^2, 9^2, ........, (n-1)^2, n^2}.
2. There are two arrays.  One is hf = {1, 4, 9, ........, n-1, n} and another one is random = {2, 3, 4, ........, k-1, k}.  I would like to multiply each component in two arrays.  {1*2, 4*3, 9*4, ......., (n-1)*(k-1), n*k}.

Actual code I used for this is as follows:

```
    int np = 20000;
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
    {
       random[i] = randomNG.GetNormal();

       for (int j = 0; j < np; j++)
       {
           sigma[j] = Math.Pow(hf[j], 2);
           hf[j] = hf[j] * random[i];
           sigma_super[j] = sigma_super[j] + sigma[j];
           hf_super[j] = hf_super[j] + hf[j];
       } 
    }
```

To do the cases above, I've used 'for' statements. The problem is it takes a lot of time to process since there is for statement in another for statement (20000x20000 iterations).

When I measured the elapsed time, it was about 14 sec.  Is there any other way to do the same thing in shorter time (maybe use matrix class from open source library)? I really want to optimize this process.

Comment: How big of arrays are we talking about?

Comment: around 20000 elements in each array.  the above is an example.  If I apply the exact equations in each step, it takes lots of time!  Thanks for reading,

Comment: well, you can do it in `n / 2` iterations if you know the size of the array beforehand

Comment: Are the two arrays in case 2 the same in length?

Comment: can I assume First array is the array of squire numbers? that is {1, 4, 9 ..... (n-1)^2, n^2} ?

Comment: yes they have the same length

Comment: yes first one is for square numbers

Comment: These are typical operations in a DSP (digital signal processing) library. Depending on the target system, there may be optimized DSP libraries available, for example from Intel for Intel processors: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp

Comment: This is for seismic ground motion study.  In each time step i, there are series of waves, j.  Very first time, I used double array [i, j] but it caused memory problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a nested for loop?  It looks, to me, like you should remove the inner for loop and change all references from variable "j" to variable "i".  Much like how my answer looks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I will revisit the equations again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two arrays of 20,000 elements (40,000 elements in total) is not that many.  How did you implement your code for it to take "a lot of time to process"?

This processed rather quickly:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array1 = new int[20000];
        int[] array2 = new int[20000];
        int[] square = new int[20000];
        int[] product = new int[20000];

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = r.Next(1, 10);
            array2[i] = r.Next(1, 10);

            square[i] = array1[i] * array1[i];
            product[i] = array1[i] * array2[i];
        }

        // Only displaying the first 20 results
        Console.WriteLine("Array1 : {0}", String.Join(",", array1.Take(20)));
        Console.WriteLine("Array2 : {0}", String.Join(",", array2.Take(20)));
        Console.WriteLine("Square : {0}", String.Join(",", square.Take(20)));
        Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", String.Join(",", product.Take(20)));
    }
}
```

Results (will vary with each execution):

```
Array1 : 4,3,4,7,3,3,5,6,3,3,9,7,5,4,4,2,8,7,4,7
Array2 : 4,7,6,7,4,6,4,8,8,3,7,2,2,7,3,2,4,2,8,3
Square : 16,9,16,49,9,9,25,36,9,9,81,49,25,16,16,4,64,49,16,49
Product: 16,21,24,49,12,18,20,48,24,9,63,14,10,28,12,4,32,14,32,21
```

See working example here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/83I3B0

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I should elaborate my question.  I edited my answer little bit to reorient the purpose of the question.  Actual case is I am dealing with for statement in for statement.  It creates lot of iterations.  I should bring this up to you.  Could you please take a look into my problem one more time?  Again, thanks for your answer,